# Properly throwing and catching Errors and Exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, exception, silex

I'm having trouble catching exceptions. Mainly this is for missing routes.

I have use `Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler` and `ExceptionHandler::register();` like the documentation says.

Also:

```
$app->error(function(\Exception $e, $code) {
switch ($code) {
    case 404:
        $message = 'The requested page could not be found.';
        break;
    default:
        $message = 'We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.';
}

return new Response($message);
});
```

But I still get a `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException`.

I am at this point, totally lost as how to proceed.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that I get a *The requested page could not be found* error when run from PHP's built-in server, but not the remote host. There just happens to be a version difference. 5.4(locally) and 5.3.3(remote).

Comment: Is it the only Exception not working?

Comment: which version of silex are you using? The 1.X branch or the *2.X@dev*?

Comment: @mTorres 1.x branch. v1.2.3 in my composer.json.

Comment: Sorry then, 2.X branch changed the signature of error handling function. At this point I can only point you to the [oficial silex skeleton project](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton/tree/1.1) to check how they setup error handling.